# CloseDate Stage history field on opportunity

Tags: opportunity, fields

Can we rename the field CloseDate of the stage history related list of opportunity?

Beside, is there a way to increment the value of this field?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this via Build / Customize / Tab Names and Labels / Rename Tabs and Labels.

As to the second question: what exactly do you mean with 'increment'? You can change this field into whatever value you want. Except when it's in the history list, because you can't change the past.